# Error:'inout IndexPath' is not convertible to 'IndexPath'

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, core-data, segue

I have a TableViewController with lists of data entry using CoreData. I also have ViewController with TextView. I have completed operation like add, save and delete on items. Now I am working on edit by linking the selected TableViewCell to TextView on next ViewController. But, I am getting error as 'inout IndexPath' is not convertible to 'IndexPath'. How to solve this error?

Comment: var indexPath : IndexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow! here is error its can not be convert like that

Comment: Himanshu Moradiya @ Sir, Plzz elaborate with solution ?? I am new to swift !!

Comment: check my answer if any query in my code then put comment .

Comment: make sure your tableview have allow permission for selection. if not then
you can do like tableView.allowsSelection = true

Comment: jignesh Vadadoriya@ It allows Sir!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
func getIndexPathForSelectedCell() -> IndexPath?
{
        var indexPath2:IndexPath?

        if TABLEVIEW.indexPathsForSelectedItems!.count > 0 {
            indexPath2 = TABLEVIEW.indexPathsForSelectedItems![0]
        }
        return indexPath2
 }

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
     if (segue.identifier == "detailView")
        {
             print("Segue Clicked.  werwerewrere..................................")
            if let indexPath2 = getIndexPathForSelectedCell()
            {
                // here write code for move to next controller.
               let YOUR_NEXT_CONTROLLER_OBJECT = segue.destination as! YOUR_NEXT_CONTROLLER_CLASS_NAME
               YOUR_NEXT_CONTROLLER_OBJECT.KEY =  PASS_DATA_VALUE
            }
        }

}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131567/discussion-on-answer-by-himanshu-moradiya-errorinout-indexpath-is-not-convert).

Answer (score 0):

```
let indexPathForSelectedRow = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow
let row: Int                = (indexPathForSelectedRow?.row)!
print(row);
```